# Load More Button Android with Limit and Offset

Tags: java, android, android-listview, pagination, limit

I have implemented a custom scroll view (not list view). Its using Intent Service to hit the server with offset and limit and display the result. For instance. i set offset = 0 and limit = FIRST_BATCH (int FIRST_BATCH = 15) for the first call. Its returning 15 names and details. And the next intent service call. I am using offset = FIRST_BATCH and limit = FIRST_BATCH. Its retuning next 15 names, from 15 to 30. And i am displaying Load More button at the end of 30 names. Here is my problem. Once i hit Load More button, i want to display the next 15 names, with offset = FIRST_BATCH + FIRST_BATCH and limit = FIRST_BATCH. And it will be growing more ..... Here is my implementation ....

```
private void startName(){ 
Intent getNameSearch = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), IntentService.class);
    getNameSearch.putExtra("search_offset", 0);
    getNameSearch.putExtra("search_limit", FIRST_BATCH);
    getNameSearch.setAction(IntentService.ACTION_GET_NAMESEARCH);
    getSherlockActivity().startService(getNameSearch);
    mCallback.onCreateProgressDialog();

    getNameSearch = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), IntentService.class);
    getNameSearch.putExtra("search_offset", FIRST_BATCH);
    getNameSearch.putExtra("search_limit", FIRST_BATCH);
    getNameSearch.setAction(IntentService.ACTION_GET_NAMESEARCH);
    getSherlockActivity().startService(getNameSearch);
    mCallback.onCreateProgressDialog();
}
```

Once the view is displayed. I am loading the LoadMore Button. And once i click the LoadMore button i am calling the intent service again. But i know this is wrong. As the offset will be always 30 everytime. So the name will be displayed from 30 to 45 all the time. I want this to grow. Say, after i click LoadMore button. I want this to be 30 to 45 and Again hit the load More button, it should be 45 to 60 and goes on ...

```
    final Button btnAddMore = (Button) myNameSearch.findViewById(R.id.loadMore);
    btnAddMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loadMoreButton = false;
    btnAddMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadMoreButton();
        }
    });
```

And here is the loadMoreSpinner method

```
private void loadMoreButton(){ 
    Intent getNameSearch = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), IntentService.class);
    int finalOffset = FIRST_BATCH * 2;
    getNameSearch.putExtra("search_offset", finalOffset);
    getNameSearch.putExtra("search_limit", FIRST_BATCH);
    getNameSearch.setAction(IntentService.ACTION_GET_NAMESEARCH);
    getSherlockActivity().startService(getNameSearch);
    mCallback.onCreateProgressDialog();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you really want to just add 15 to both values when you push that button.

Comment: Thats correct. Everytime i push ... it has to have 15 more to the offset. For instance. When i load first time, the offset will be 0 then 15. When i hit Load More offset supposed to be 30. And when i hit load more again. It has to be 45. But i am not sure how to pass that. Thank you

Comment: Track the current offset / limit with variables, add 15 to ones you need in the `onClick()`. Voila.